# HTML5 audio element vanishes in IPythonNB container widget

Tags: python, widget, html5-audio, jupyter-notebook, interactive

This code:

```
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.html import widgets
snd = """
<audio controls="controls" style="width:600px height:100px">
<source controls src="data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRiYAAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAYCIAAAATAQAIAEAAZGF0YQgAAAAAAA==" type="audio/wav" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>"""
snd_widget = widgets.HTML(snd)
container = widgets.Box(children=[snd_widget])
display(container)
```

...produces my audio player within the container widget like I expect, but then promptly vanishes.  It actually has a nice fade-away effect.  However, I do not wish it to disappear; I want to be able to interact with it.  It is briefly visible again if I close the interactive element, so I have to believe there is some simple display bug I hope to work around.

`snd_widget.disabled` is `False` and `snd_widget.visible` is `True`

`display(snd_widget)` (without using ContainerWidget/Box) has the same effect.

Problem seems browser-specific:  Problem exists on Firefox, but display seems fine on Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Firefox's behavior for malformed audio files.  Unfortunately both my work sample and this simple test sample were both malformed.  Firefox will hide the player if it can't play the file, Chromium will grey out the player after a short time.